# Iterating for loop for set number of iterations each time it is called until the end of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a preload images function which I would like to use to preload 2 images each time it is called, until all the images are preloaded.
This is my function:

```js
function preload() {
  for (i; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image()
    images[i].src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[i]
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to achieve that, to be able to change start and number of iterations (2) each time it is called, until the whole array of images is preloaded?

**Updated**

This is my full script:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var imagesIndex = 0;
    var loadedImages = new Array();
    var nextImage = 0;
    preload();

    function preload() {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (nextImage < images.length) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage];
                loadedImages[nextImage] = img;
                ++nextImage;
            }
        }
    }

    $('#forward').click(function() {
      imagesIndex++;
      preload();

      if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 1)) {
          imagesIndex = 0;
      }

      $('#image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + loadedImages[imagesIndex], "alt" : name});
    });

    $('#back').click(function() {
        imagesIndex--;

        if (imagesIndex < 0) {
            imagesIndex = (loadedImages.length - 1);
        }

        $('#image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + loadedImages[imagesIndex], "alt" : name});
    });
});
```

Here I have forward and back functions on which I would like to call preload function to iterate 2 times.

Comment: you use the same array for iterating and assigning. but that does overwrite the former content. btw, you start index is not set.

Comment: Is this an Image slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of where you are in the array outside the function. But first, you have to fix the problem that you're overwriting what I assume is the URL of the image with the `Image` object *before* you grab that URL.

For instance:

```
var nextImage = 0;
function preload() {
    preload1();
    preload1();
}
function preload1() {
    if (nextImage < images.length) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage];
        images[nextImage] = img;
        ++nextImage;
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use a loop instead of `preload1`.

Comment: I have updated my question with your code. I would just like to ask you what am I supposed to have when I show the images, am I using the images from loadedImages array or images array like so: `$('#image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + loadedImages[imagesIndex], "alt" : name});`

Comment: @Marco: *"I have updated my question with your code."* That's not how SO works. Questions remain questions in (largely) their original form. Answers are *separate*. Editing the question to fold answers into them is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for that, I will post another question about it and mark yours as a correct one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177018/preloading-and-showing-images-with-javascript). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var imageList = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png'];
var _images = imageList.slice(0);
var STATIC_PATH = '/imagecache/cover/';

function loadImage(image) {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = STATIC_PATH + image;
  return img
}

function loadNImages(n) {
  var tmp = _images.splice(0, (n || 1));
  return tmp.map(function(img) {
    return loadImage(img);
  })
}

function initTimeout() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var imgs = loadNImages(2);
    imgs.forEach(function(img){
      document.querySelector('.content').append(img)
    })
    if (_images.length > 0) {
      initTimeout();
    }
  }, 1000)
}
initTimeout()
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```