# Preloading and showing images with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

To continue on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176160/iterating-for-loop-for-set-number-of-iterations-each-time-it-is-called-until-the) here. Since I am doing this for the first time, and I still consider myself a newbie in javascript I would like to know how to properly preload images for the browser.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imagesIndex = 0;
    var loadedImages = new Array();
    var nextImage = 0;
    preload();

    function preload() {
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (nextImage < images.length) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage];
                loadedImages[nextImage] = img;
                ++nextImage;
            }
        }
    }

    $('#forward').click(function() {
      imagesIndex++;
      preload();

      if (imagesIndex > (loadedImages.length - 1)) {
          imagesIndex = 0;
      }

      $('#image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + loadedImages[imagesIndex], "alt" : name});
    });

    $('#back').click(function() {
        imagesIndex--;

        if (imagesIndex < 0) {
            imagesIndex = (loadedImages.length - 1);
        }

        $('#image').attr({"src" : '/imagecache/cover/' + loadedImages[imagesIndex], "alt" : name});
    });
});
```

I am getting images from the global array images, and then using preload function to preload 2 at the time. I wonder what do I need to send as a source to the image element. Is that a src from the loadedImages array element or from the images array?

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean, you are already defining the source of `loadedImages` from `images` (`img.src = '/imagecache/cover/' + images[nextImage]`). When accessing them you can just do `loadedImages[i].src`.

Comment: yes, that is what I wasn't sure about, thank you!